# Why does adding a decimal point change the eigenvector?

Tags: matrix, eigenvalues

I am computing the spectrum of a matrix:

[image]

When I add a decimal point to the argument, then one of the eigenvectors corresponding to the eigenvalue 2 turns out to be different in the two cases. What is going on?

Here is a copy of the code for reference:

````
m = {{0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0},{0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1},{0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0},{1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0},{0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1},{0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0},{1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0},{0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0}};

f[b_]:= {MatrixForm[Round[Eigenvalues[b*m],0.001]],MatrixForm[Round[Eigenvectors[b*m],0.001]]};

{f[1],f[1.0]};
```
````

Comment: Sorry about that. I have added the code to my question. Thanks.

Comment: Because Mathematica converts all numbers to machine precision floating point numbers if a decimal point is present. Numerically, this is the most efficent precision. But _Mathematica_ also provides routines for exact numbers and for arbitrary precision numbers. That's at least three totally separate algorithms, hence different results. For example, _Mathematica_ orthonormalizes eigenvectors only if finite precision is employed.

Comment: It is also important to note that scaling (multiplying) an eigenvector by a constant does not change it from being an eigenvector. So the second version is just scaled version of the first. Both are valid eigenvectors. There will be a problem if one eigenvector changes orientation. But no problem if it only changes length.

Comment: `MatrixForm` is a wrapper intended for display only. By including it in the definition of `f` you make any subsequent calculations with `f` more difficult. Just use `MatrixForm` when you want to display the results. For example, `f2[b_] := Eigensystem[b*m];` then `MatrixForm /@ f2[1]`

Answer (score 7):

Look at the eigen values/vectors from the first example:

[image]

and from the second example:

[image]

[image]

Then from the help:

[image]

Therefore, the eigenvectors in the first example a not normalized, in the second, they are.

Note however, it could be worse. Because the eigenvectors are degenerate, any linear combination will also be eigenvectors to the same eigen value.